# Fourier transformation of a discrete function; conclusion of having a finite sum

Tags: fourier-transform

For a function $g$ defined at discrete points $x_n = n a$ with $n \in \{0, \ldots, N\}$ with periodicity $g(x_0) = g(x_N)$ the discrete Fourier transformation reads

$g(x_n) = \frac{1}{Na} \sum_{q \in 2 \pi \mathbb{Z}/Na} \tilde{g}(q) \mathrm{e}^{ \mathrm{i}  q x_n} $

with inverse transformation

$\tilde{g}(q) = a \sum_{i=1}^N g(x_n) \mathrm{e}^{ \mathrm{i } q x_n}$.

Now from $\tilde{g}(q) = \tilde{g}(q + 2 \pi m /a)$ for $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ one should be able to see, that the expression above simplifies to

$g(x_n) = \frac{1}{Na} \sum_{q_m} \tilde{g}(q_m) \mathrm{e}^{ \mathrm{i}  q_m x_n} $ with $q_m = 2 \pi m / Na$ and $m = 0, \ldots N-1$.

I am having trouble making this conclusion and would be grateful if someone could help.

Comment: $x_n = na$ so $e^{i q x_n} = e^{i (q+2\pi/a) x_n}$ and $\bar{g}(q) =\bar{g}(q+2\pi /a)$. In general there is no simplification for $g(x_n)$. Next time avoid those awful notations and use the usual ones and look at periodicity, upsampling and downsampling laws for the DFT.

Comment: I am very sorry, but I still don't get it:

On the one hand...
The formulas I gave above follow from expanding a function $g \colon [0, N\cdot a] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ via the usual Fourier series and approximating the integral in the formula for the inverse transformation $\tilde{g}(q) = (\ldots)$ by a sum.

But on the other hand... In the [Wikipedia-article on discrete-Fourier-transformations][1] one sees formulas (for both: $g(x_n)$ and $\tilde{g}(q)$) given by finite sums.

I don't get the difference: One calls both "discrete Fourier-transformation". (?)